# IF THEN ELSE statement issues

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to create a email which has a link depending on a certain value.

In the data extension `candidate_discipline__c_Salesforce`, the primary key is `candidate__c` and the column where I want to look in is `Name`.

This data extension is a related list in Salesforce.

So depending on which discipline a candidate has i want to show a different URL.

For instance: 
If he is a "Drilling engineer" then show URL in mail `www.surveygizmo.com/drilling-engineer`. 
If he is a `Rigger` then show URL in mail `www.surveygizmo.com/rigger`.

I'm quite new to AMPscript, this is what i tried doing but it's not working:

```
%%[
    var @discipline
    set @discipline = Lookup("Candidate_Discipline__c_Salesforce", "Candidate__c", "Name", "Surveyor")
]%%


%%[IF @discipline == "Surveyor" THEN]%% <a href="https://www.surveygizmo.com/surveyor">Surveyor</a>

%%[ELSEIF @discipline == "Rigger" THEN]%% <a href="https://www.surveygizmo.com/rigger">Rigger</a>

%%[ELSEIF @discipline == "Trainer" THEN]%% <a href="https://www.surveygizmo.com/trainer">Trainer</a>

%%[ELSEIF @discipline == "Outlander" THEN]%% <a href="https://www.surveygizmo.com/engineer">Engineer</a>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Can someone help me with this code?

Please find below a sample of de Data Extension:

**Name**                    **Candidate__c**                        **BusinessLine__c**                         **Job_Title__c**
Chief Engineer      003200000142TJAAA2          a1Sw00000033FFYEA2         a0cw0000008yEaEAAU
Able Seaman         003w0000018fYM3AAM        a1Sw00000014jMbEAI         a0cw0000006qk50AAA

Skipper                 003w000001LBxFMAA1        a1Sw00000014jMbEAI         a0cw0000006YD7SAAW

**Desired output:**
I am going to run a journey for all Chief Engineers, Able Seamans and Skippers. Those will receive a email with a link which is specific for THAT discipline. Skippers will get a link to a self-assessment form for Skippers and Chief Engineers will receive a link to a self-assessment form for Chief Engineers.

The journey will be on the `Contact_Salesforce` Data Extension. The `Candidate_Discipline__c_Salesforce` will be AMPscripted in the email as i tried to do.

Comment: What in `Contact_Salesforce` indicates `Chief Engineer`, `Able Seaman`, etc?  Is it `Candidate__c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it:

```
%%[

var @ContactID, @Candidate__c, @discipline, @name, @surveyCode

/* id for contact from send context */
set @ContactID = AttributeValue("ID") 

/* retrieve column value from Contact for discipline name lookup */
set @Candidate__c = Lookup("Contact_Salesforce", "Candidate__c", "ID", @ContactID)

/* retrieve discipline name from Candidate_Discipline__c */
set @discipline = Lookup("Candidate_Discipline__c_Salesforce", "Name", "Candidate__c", @Candidate__c)

/* set survey code based on discipline */
if @discipline == "Surveyor" then
  set @surveyCode = "surveyor123" 
elseif @discipline = "Rigger" then
  set @surveyCode = "rigger284" 
elseif @discipline = "Trainer" then
  set @surveyCode = "trainer381" 
elseif @discipline = "Outlander" then
  set @surveyCode = "outlander582" 
else
  raiserror("survey code not found")
endif


]%%
<a href='%%=redirectto(concat(https://www.surveygizmo.com/",lowercase(@surveyCode)))=%%'>Complete Survey</a>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your help. The link behind https://www.surveygizo.com/ will be generated by surveygizmo. So for surveyor it could be http://www.surveygizmo.com/surveyor4342/. So i want to put all links in the AMPscript manually. How could i do that? + I want to do a lookup to all disciplines not only surveyor, so this shouldn't be static value.

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: Adam you're the king. Only thing is our data model is a little bit weird. So "Name" is not a name of a person but the name of a discipline (for instance Surveyor). "Candidate_Discipline__c_Salesforce" is a related list, so if two records in the related list are "Surveyor" AND "Rigger" then i want to show both links.

Comment: If you could update your question with a sampling of data from your `Candidate_Discipline__c_Salesforce` DE that'd be helpful.  Also include the desired output.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for the late reply, i was off work. Now i am on again. I updated my question above with a DE sample + desired output. Hope you can help

Comment: Updated my answer above.